# Convert external css to inline in Nextjs13

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js, tailwind-css, next.js13

I am trying to convert the external css to embed but have not found any solution yet for nextjs 13. Any leads on this would be highly appreciated.

I tried critters, html-inline-css-webpack-plugin and also tried converting by creating _document file, reading styles and putting inside style tag but could not achieve the result.

Comment: Please add more information about what library are you using and what have you tried up till now.

Comment: I have mentioned that i have used critters package as well as html-inline-css-webpack-plugin in the description itself.

Comment: Can you perhaps include some code snippets of examples of what you've attempted, or any more information about what *specifically* you've done while trying to implement these?